# Concurrent handling in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When updating the field like this it will lock the field:

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1
```

Since this is a part of a counter that is expecting a bit of a load, I am afraid not all the count will be registred when multiple users comes to my site.

Is there a better way or a fix of doing this?

Comment: If it didn't lock the column, then imagine concurrent updates where both assume field is 54 and write 55 instead of what it should be, 56.

Comment: You could also do a log table. Instead of updating, add them to a table with refering ID. (to avoid useless data, you can use a cron job for cleanup)

Comment: @CharlesForest That would be nice. _Time/date_ and _1_ in the table?

Comment: yes, just keep your logs simple. i usually do Time/date - UserID(if needed) - you can use SELECT COUNT(*), no need of a column filled with 1's.

Comment: @CharlesForest Thanks. I find it funny how I started with a little counter, but had to a lot further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution:

```
 UPDATE table SET field = field + 1
```

is absolutely perfect. That is a single SQL statement, which is fully executed without side effect or not at all. All you could additionally do is, to check weather your statement was actually executed. If not, you could retry to execute it. But there is no real reason for that. You can leave it as it is... In most cases when correctly written statements fail, there is another reason (like an overloaded DB) and retrying would make things even worse.

If you only have short write/read accesses to that table everything is fine; if concurrent commands need to access it, they will wait until the lock is freed and they will execute then.

Only if you have very time consuming operations on THAT same table that take more than 1-2 seconds to execute. Then you might loose some countings. The timeout to wait for aquiring the lock is usually something as 10 oder 30 seconds. You could also loose counts, if a process does just manually lock the table (e.g. "LOCK table") and does not free it. This would be a bug ... Other SQL statements wouldnt be able to aquire a lock and finally would be aborted after some longer waiting period.

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly good explanation! How about I only count to the database and not over-doing it by going into tables etc?

Comment: For such counting jobs, one small table is fine. Put different things in different tables and they dont interfere. And: Always (if possible) use a single UPDATE with calculations in it, instead of a "SELECT => calculation in Script => UPDATE".

Comment: Ok :) How about the request for the script? Should I go for GET or POST in XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: You should use POST. Reason: You change the state of the requested resource (count something up). Therefore you should use POST, even GET would work. GET requests are for requests that can be repeated without side effects.

Comment: Looks good! Now you can improve it... create a new table, which has two columns. Give this table a name that explains it's use this time, as "counters". The columns should be "id" and "num"; then add a parameter "id" to your php script and increase the column num of the table entry with matches id = $id... Then you'll get closer to what databases are used for.

Comment: Hint: You can combine an INSERT and an UPDATE as like "INSERT INTO counters (id, num) VALUES ('$id', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num=num+1"; This creates new counter columns with id $id, if they don't exist and sets num to 1 (first count) or increases them by 1; But therefore you need to define column "id" as PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't got so much experience with PHP, but I will make it.

Answer (score 6):

myisam engine is always locking table before executing transaction, so other concurrent transactions will be forced to wait until this one will be done

Comment: So technically, the requests are set on wait?

Comment: yea, mysql keeps all other transactions waiting on the same table and perform them one by one, your only problem could be if you will make two transactions in your application for example right after updating you select those fields, you could see wrong values becouse concurrent connection incremented it meanwhile

Comment: How does Facebook etc. handle that?

Comment: I think Facebook uses a very relaxant strategy, where it may happen that some counts are lost. I assume this, as statistics are often fluctuating when requesting (e.g. number of views of posting goes up and down while it should be monotonically increasing). So this is not a good example ;-) -- This fluctuations are most likely due to distributed algorithms, meaning: there are a lot of servers that handle requests and count them, and later they are accumulated by joining information of servers. But depending on which of the many servers you access, the (still intermediate) sum is different...

Comment: For now, just keep in mind that one database server is easy to manage. If load increases you can upgrade it's hardware... If that's not enough, you hopefully have few write operations and a lot of read operations. Then you can replicate everything from one master server (used for read/write accesses) to some slave servers (read access only). And if this doesn't help: it really starts becoming very complicated...